# Loop over List to fetch key & value pairs using Java

Tags: java, iteration

This is the response I receive:

```
[{rollno=1066276530, rollvalue=1815401000238}]
```

This is cast to `List<Map<String, String>> leadIds`. Now I want to iterate these leadIds to get the key & value pairs. I have tried in this way, but that is returning key as "1066276530" and value as "rollno", whereas I am expecting key as "1066276530" and value as "1815401000238".

Here is my code

```
for (Map<String, String> map : leadIds) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String rollno = String.valueOf(entry.getValue());
        String rollvalue = String.valueOf(entry.getKey());
        LOG.info("[Status Search] Roll No:" +rollno
            + " Roll value:" + rollvalue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take 10 mins to look at your code, line by line, before asking a question here. You could've solved this issue very easily yourself.

Comment: The problem isn't where you read the map, which is correct, but where you construct it. Every entry on your map has a value of "id". Post the part of your code where you construct the map.

Comment: @RoelStrolenberg what do you mean?

Comment: Your loop needs to be in the outer loop, not the inner. The outer loop iterates over the actual elements in your map, the inner contains the ket-value pair, but as you want the key, only the value, I suggest you move the log to the outer loop. 5 mins of debugging could've told you this as well, hence the remark.

Comment: Can you update the code with the snippet if you don't mind

Answer (score 3):

Look at your log statement. You have switched around the number and ID:

```
LOG.info("[Status Search] Application ID :"+applicationNumber+
    " Application Number :"+appId);
```

Should be:

```
LOG.info("[Status Search] Application ID :"+appId+
    " Application Number :"+applicationNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 for (Map<String, String> map : leadIds) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String applicationNumber = String.valueOf(entry.getkey());
        String appVal = String.valueOf(entry.getValue());
        LOG.info("[Status Search] Application ID :"+applicationNumber+" Application Number :"+appVal);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need two loops to achieve this, your outer loop `map` contains the values for the keys `rollno` and `rollvalue`, so get it from there.

```
for (Map<String, String> map : leadIds) {
    String applicationNumber = map.get("rollno");
    String appId = map.get("rollvalue");
    LOG.info("[Status Search] Application ID:"+ applicationNumber + " Application Number:" + appId);
}
```